# UICollectionViewCell Snap to Centre

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have added a UICollectionView which will have 5 cells, scrolling horizontally. I would like the user to be able to scroll between the cells, where each cell will snap to the centre. Here is a my UICollectionFlowLayout code used with the cell sizes etc.

```
-(UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionLayout{

if (!_collectionLayout) {
    _collectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    _collectionLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    _collectionLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 30;
    _collectionLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    _collectionLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(200, 165);
    _collectionLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 65, 0, 55);
    _collectionLayout.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    }
return _collectionLayout;
}
```

I have added insets so the first and last cell stops in the middle, though any of the three cells in between don't. Please see attached screen-shots to illustrate -[2 screen shots below]

I can easily achieve centralised paging of the cells if they are the width of the screen or I simply make 5 sections, however if I do this, then the user does not see the other cells left or right, which I need so they know there is more to scroll to, if you know what I mean.

I have read similar answers about disabling paging and using `scrollViewWillEndDragging` methods, but I could not get these to work either.

If anyone can offer any clear way to do this that would be great,

Thanks in advance

Jim

[image: First Cell which is fine]

[image: Second cell - not centred]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely won't be the solution you're ideally looking for, though it's an option you can use, as I have used for the set up you describe.

Increase your Uicollectionviewcell size to the width of the screen, with your purple square as view centralised within the cell. Remove your section inset code and change line spacing to =0.

At the left and right sides of the cell place arrow images (or as button), or a swipe gesture icon so app user knows there's more. As you've only got 5 cells, have cell at IndexPath.row==0 and IndexPath.row==4 to hide their left and right 'more' arrows respectively.